# Image became gray with Storypencil addon in Blender

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor, grease-pencil

I am using the Storypencil addon to draw in Blender,  but I have a problem. When I switch to the video editing panel, the colors of my drawings become gray. How can I fix this? Is there a setting I need to change? Please help me out, I really want to use this addon for my animation project.
[image: My drawing]
[image: Video Editing]

Comment: try setting Surface Strength to 5 in the Properties / World menu.